# Why are many conversations in Tanach between two parties exclusively

Tags: tanach, speech-talking

Inspired by a [comment on this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/106580/are-there-examples-in-tanach-of-3-or-more-parties-having-an-ongoing-conversation/106588?noredirect=1#comment357569_106580) it seems the vast majority, if not the entirety, of conversations in Tanach are between two and only two parties. I would like to understand conceptually why this would be the case.

Comment: Isn't that usually the case in life as well?

Comment: To the extent that conversations in Tanakh aren't precise historical records of actual speech between people (it's not like Paroh spoke those words to Moshe _in Hebrew_) but rather stories being told to convey certain content and play certain characters/concepts against each other, it's not surprising that the extra complication of writing a multi-party discussion didn't make it to the text much. The point isn't like a novel to show a relatable scene realistically. Same reason conversations are often very short and choppy. You can barely read any dialogue in Tanakh like a play.

Comment: Can you qualify "conversations in Tanac"h"? Almost all of books such as Yirmiyahu and Yeshayu might qualify as a "conversation" to the entire B'nai Yisra'el. Otherwise, isn't the definition of a conversation automatically between two people? How can you properly hear a response from more than one simultaneously?

Comment: @DoubleAA sounds like an answer